# Thousands of Annoying warnings during "mvn process-resources". [WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, java-7

During the **mvn clean process-resources**, I am getting very annoying warnings for thousnads of times per module. This slows down the build process itself.

```
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.SystemPropertyProfileActivator@5b6867
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.JdkPrefixProfileActivator@1af8109
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.SystemPropertyProfileActivator@5b6867
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.JdkPrefixProfileActivator@1af8109
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.SystemPropertyProfileActivator@5b6867
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.JdkPrefixProfileActivator@1af8109
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.SystemPropertyProfileActivator@5b6867
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.JdkPrefixProfileActivator@1af8109
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.SystemPropertyProfileActivator@5b6867
[WARNING] Component returned which is not the same manager. Ignored. component=org.apache.maven.profiles.activation.JdkPrefixProfileActivator@1af8109
```

Background Information: 
I am using java 1.7 and apache-maven-2.2.1

**java -version:**

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**mvn -version**

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530)
Java version: 1.7.0_15
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

Comment: Can you show the pom file otherwise it's hard to guess what's wrong. Furthermore why are you using an old Maven version?